# Is it possible to set the framerate of an animated image texture?

Tags: texturing

My project's frame rate is 24fps. I have an animated image texture that is a 64-frame image sequence. It needs to run at 18fps. Is there any way to do this? Here is how the texture is currently set up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot set the framerate in the *Node Editor* differently for specific sequences (better answers welcome). If I understand the question correctly, you need your project to keep the 24 fps, right? If not, just set it to 18 fps if that's what you need for the image sequence.

If you instead want to play it slower than the project framerate, you could load the sequence into the *Video Editor* and add an *Effect Strip* > *Speed Control* to it.

Set the *Speed Factor* to 18/24 = 0.75 and stretch the sequence to a rounded 85 frames. Now render the 85 frames as a new image sequence so you can use it in your 24 fps project and it will be about 3.5 seconds long like it would have been at 18 fps. Unfortunately this results cross-fading images that are put inbetween the existing.

This is just a workaround in lack of a better solution. Of course you wouldn't have to re-render if you would only be working in the *Video Editor* combining multiple image sequences with different speeds - in this case you just keep them adjusted by the *Speed Control Effect Strip*.

Comment: thank you, it looks like I can't do what I want to do, so I will use your video editor method to convert the 18fps texture to 24fps and reimport it into the project.